# Repetir el registro padre o primer registro de cada grupo sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2017

Nececito ayuda para resolver la consulta que esta en la imagen se los agradeceria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [**Aquí no hacemos tareas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320). ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas has tenido? El enunciado y el código deben ir _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: No coloques imágenes referentes al texto de tu pregunta y menos el código de la misma, edita y coloca todo como texto y el código dale formato, aquí puedes leer [ask]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Hola puedes hacer esto

```
SELECT T2.ID, T1.Grupo, T1.Valor FROM Tabla T1
    LEFT JOIN Tabla T2 ON T2.Grupo = T1.Grupo
WHERE T1.ID IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Tabla GROUP BY GRUPO)
```

Con **(SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Tabla GROUP BY GRUPO)** obtienes los primeros registros del grupo

Y luego con el left join vas a agarrar todos los elementos del grupo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una sección de [answer] es ¡Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**! Evita responder a preguntas en donde el OP no haya demostrado un mínimo esfuerzo en resolver el planteamiento. [es.so] no es un servicio de código, o como se lo conoce en inglés, _gimme the codez_. Ni siquiera colocó el enunciado como texto...

Comment: Gracias me funciono a la primera